# Best way to display multiple lines of static text in C#?

Tags: c#, text, lines

I am making a prompt in C# that instructs the user how to use the program before they can access it.

What is the best way to display multiple lines of static text? Using a bunch labels doesn't seem like it would be the proper way... xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a text input box marked as read-only and multi-line.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WinForms, you might want to consider adding a WebBrowser control to your form - you can then point the browser to an html file you send with the program. This allows you to use all of html to instruct your users, as well as point them to, say, your web site for more help or information.

Comment: Great Idea! I will use this in the future, but it is not necessary for this project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One label can contain multiple lines of text if the text has newlines in it.